# How to use `intelephense` to remove blank lines when format my php script in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, intelephense

My system is centos 7.6,intelephense1.3.11,vs code 1.44.1

```
$options = array(  
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE    => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false
);  
// Create a new PDO instanace  
$pdo= new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);  
$pdo->exec("set names utf8");




$groupsql = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM lime_groups WHERE sid=' .$survey_id.' ORDER BY group_order');
$groupres = $groupsql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I just want to format my script by remove the blank line ,right indent.
As to above script,I `ctrl+A`,and then `ctrl +shift +I`,blank lines still there.
How to use `intelephense` to remove blank lines when format my php script in vs code?

Answer (score 1):

This is because Intelephense does not support this. Also PSR-2/PSR-12 don't cover such lines, because they (believe it or not) can be intentional.

So you have only two options here:

1. [Add this as feature request issue on Github](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense)
2. [Use one of the many plugins that provide this functionally](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LucasAMello.blanklineplus)

P.S. the real reason why I answer this question: [your application is highly vulnerable to SQL Injections](https://www.acunetix.com/blog/articles/prevent-sql-injection-vulnerabilities-in-php-applications/) as you don't escape the the parameters passed to your SQL query at all.